# What is the difference between Computer Organization and Computer Architecture?

Tags: computer-architecture, instruction-set

I am still not getting a clear picture from any textbooks. Anyone, please elaborate with examples. What does 8086 architecture block diagram refer to?

Comment: This site is for specific technical questions only; queries about somewhat academic categorizations of things aren't really specific technical questions, especially when they may be distinctions fairly local to a given textbook or class.

Comment: @tlfong01 When a microprocessor architecture block diagram is mentioned, isn't it mentioning the hardware requirement & interconnection? Then, why its called architecture? Shouldn't be it called organization?

Comment: There are not any rigorous definitions that everybody agrees. The two kinds of text books cover more or less the same stuff. However, "architecture" focuses a little bit more on computer human interface. "Organization" focuses a little bit more on structure and interaction among subsystems. So you see building architects focus on how people feels when using or living in a building. On the other hand, when business managers talks about their "organization chart", they emphasize on the internal hierarchy, ...

Comment: @Chris Stratton, I was expecting some technical examples to differentiate these two terms. Like, the choice between serial adder and parallel adder in  ALU as an example of computer organization.

Comment: Stack exchange is for questions which have *specific answers* - questions seeking a list of examples are off topic.

Comment: You might to ask Linda, who has written a best seller: "Essentials Of Computer Organization And Architecture - Linda Null":
https://www.bookdepository.com/Essentials-Of-Computer-Organization-And-Architecture-Linda-Null/9781284123036?redirected=true&utm_medium=Google&utm_campaign=Base3&utm_source=HK&utm_content=Essentials-Of-Computer-Organization-And-Architecture&selectCurrency=HKD&w=AFF1AU96C8ZNXSA8VCXV&pdg=pla-317692435101:cmp-8783422496:adg-92224525801:crv-410452267580:pos-:dev-c&gclid=Cj0KCQjwtsv7BRCmARIsANu-CQepcbPZemwPH9rpTH9TUUqAW2Or-PtAjL6k_w2rHxg2uX0GUx_JYoQaAqJ7EALw_wcB.

Comment: @Lelouch Yagami, well, when you study a microprocessor, you might focus on the internal organization of how the ALU, RAM, ROM, hard disks talk to each other. But when you study the "peripheral" subsystems such a UART, USART, bus, Ethernet controllers, hard disk, etc, you will focus on how the microprocessor interface with the external world, not necessary humans. / to continue, ...

Comment: There is no dictionary of defined terms around this. Many people use 'organisation' and 'architecture' interchangeably. We can throw in structure and topology as additional synonyms. Get over it. Understand what it means, and don't stress on what it's called.

Comment: As I said, there is not clear dividing line. You remind me that once I studied "Computing" in the computing and control department of a college. But the teachers then actually taught architecture, because they, (von Neuman, Alam Turing, E (programs must stored in memory) E Dijkstra (No no, we must have distributed, networked computers) etal like building architects designed and built computers in the 1940/1950's.  The C&C Department previously belonged to the Maths Dept and Maths Dept and Physics Dept belonged to the Philosophy Department,...

Comment: @tlfong01 Thank you for the Null pointer!

Comment: @Brian Drummond You are welcome. BTW, I am a Taoist programmer. I love Null pointer. Cheers.

Comment: @Lelouch Yagami A cheat sheet for you: https://i.imgur.com/u2VnUQi.jpg. Happy learning. Cheers.

Comment: @ tlfong01, Thank you for recommending Linda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computer Organization and Computer Architecture are not mutually exclusive definitions. In fact, Computer Organization is a **proper subset** of
Computer Architecture.

1. Computer Architecture includes the study of Instruction Set Architecture Design. Computer Organization does not include the study of Instruction Set Architecture Design.
2. Computer Organization refers to the high-level aspects of the design of a computer. Computer Organization is also known as microarchitecture. It is about the implementation of computer designs.
3. Two computers can have the same Instruction Set Architecture, but different micro-architecture.

8086 architecture block diagram refers to microarchitecture / organization. This organization can be considered a subset of its complete architecture, which includes the instruction set.